# What is the query for this complex job

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables

```
Materials Groups
-------------------------------
|GrpID | GrpName | GrpParentID |
-------------------------------

Materials
--------------------------------------
|MatID | MatName | MatGroupID |Price |
--------------------------------------

Stores
-----------------------------
|StID | StName | StParentID |
-----------------------------

BillType
--------------------
|TypeID | TypeName |
--------------------
```

those are the types

```
Store Out
Store In/Price
Sales Return
First Period Inventory
Sales
End Period Inventory
Store Out/Price
Purchase
Store In
Ready Product In
Purchase Return
Sales Return1
Raw Materials Out

Bills
----------------------------------
|BillID | BillType| Client..|....|
----------------------------------

BillItems
---------------------------------
|ItemID| MatID| quantity|BillID |
---------------------------------
```

The required is to show report in this form
[image: the report design]

I think it's a big miss , I don't know what to do

### I tried joins , pivots ,, but i got incomplete report I think it is very complicated

**This is my latest try**

```
declare @table1 table
(
    MatGUID uniqueidentifier,
    TypeGUID uniqueidentifier,
    Qty int
)
declare @table2 table
(
    MatGroup varchar(250),
    MatName varchar(250),
    BillTypeName varchar(250),
    Qty int
)
insert into @table1
select fatoraitem.MatGUID, fatora.TypeGUID, SUM(fatoraitem.Qty) as Qty
from bi000 fatoraitem
left join bu000 as fatora on fatora.GUID = fatoraitem.ParentGUID
left join bt000 as fatoratype on fatoratype.GUID = fatora.TypeGUID
group by fatoraitem.MatGUID, fatora.TypeGUID


insert into @table2
select gr000.Name as MatGroup, mt000.Name MatName, bt000.Name as BillTypeName, t1.Qty from @table1 t1
left join mt000 on mt000.GUID = t1.MatGUID
left join bt000 on bt000.GUID = t1.TypeGUID
left join gr000 on mt000.GroupGUID = gr000.GUID

declare
    @StoreCols nvarchar(max),
    @BillTypeCols nvarchar(max),
    @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @BillTypeCols = isnull(@BillTypeCols + ', ', '') + '[' + T.BillTypeName + ']' from (select distinct BillTypeName from @table2) as T

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Results
select * into #Results from @table2
select @stmt = 'select * from #results as T
        pivot 
        (
            sum(T.Qty)
            for T.BillTypeName in (' + @BillTypeCols + ')
        ) as P'

exec sp_executesql  @stmt
```

Comment: Are there any defined relationships between your tables? Once you get the data, how are you displaying it (i.e., app front end, Excel, etc)?

Comment: [Materials] has id of its [Materials Groups], [Bills] has id of [BillType], [BillItems] has id of [Bills], id of [Stores], id of [materials], that was the relation and it will be displayed an my application.

Comment: What have you tried - post your SQL attempts and you have a better chance of someone helping you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an Excel Pivot Table to display this?

Comment: my task is to display this in the software that has it's custom way of display

Comment: What is that software?  Because this makes no sense: SQL Server does not do display formatting like your "required form" shows.  It has no ability to either color cells nor to span column headers, it just returns data in simple tabular format.  Excel can do it, but not SQL Server, so you're using the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the people vote down? instead of editing the question, giving advice in comment or answering the question the people vote down.

I finally solved it it's not solved 100% it's 90%, in other words the accumulation of stores not working[it calculates the quantity for the materials in a store, but for a parent store it don't sum the children stores]
this is the sql

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvancedBillMatReport]
@ParamUserGuid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
@ParamMaterialguid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 0X0,
@ParamGroupLevel AS int = 0,
@ParamStoreGuid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 0X0,
@ParamDisplayType AS int = 1,
@ParamPriceType AS int = 0, 
@ParamBillTypesGuidsStr AS varchar(max)  = NULL
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Result') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Result
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Results
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SecViol') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SecViol
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SecViols') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SecViols
CREATE TABLE [#SecViol] (Type [INT], Cnt [INT])
CREATE TABLE [#SecViols] (Type [INT], Cnt [INT])
--BILLTYPES
declare @BillTYpesGuids table
(
    TypeGUID uniqueidentifier,
    TypeName varchar(250)
)
insert into @BillTYpesGuids
select t1.GUID AS TypeGUID, bt000.Name AS TypeName from splitstring ( @ParamBillTypesGuidsStr, ';' ) t1 left join bt000 on bt000.GUID = t1.GUID

--MATRIALS the actual vertical part of thetable
declare @Materials table
(
    MatGUID uniqueidentifier,
    GroupGuid uniqueidentifier,
    Code varchar(250),
    Name varchar(250),
    LatinName varchar(250),
    [Level] int,
    [Path] [VARCHAR](8000),
    [Type] int
)
insert into @Materials
exec  repMattreeReport

--/////////////FILTER MATERIALS///////////////////////////////
DELETE FROM @Materials WHERE (Level < @ParamGroupLevel)
IF @ParamMaterialguid <> 0X0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @Materials WHERE MatGUID <> @ParamMaterialguid
END
SELECT * INTO #Result FROM @Materials
exec prcCheckSecurity @ParamUserGuid
DELETE FROM @Materials WHERE MatGUID NOT IN (SELECT MatGUID FROM #Result)
DROP TABLE #Result
INSERT INTO #SecViols SELECT * FROM #SecViol
TRUNCATE TABLE #SecViol
--/////////////DONE FILTERING//////////////////////////

--STORES the repeated Horizontal parts of table
declare @stores table
(
    StoreGuid uniqueidentifier,
    Name varchar(250),
    ParentGUID uniqueidentifier,
    Level int
)
insert into @stores(StoreGuid, Name, ParentGUID, Level)
SELECT T1.GUID AS StoreGuid, st000.Name, st000.ParentGUID, T1.Level FROM fnGetStoresListTree(@ParamStoreGuid, 1) AS T1 LEFT JOIN st000 ON T1.GUID = st000.GUID 

--/////////////FILTER STORES///////////////////////////

SELECT * INTO #Result1 FROM @stores
exec prcCheckSecurity @ParamUserGuid,0,0,'#Result1'
DELETE FROM @stores WHERE StoreGuid NOT IN (SELECT StoreGuid FROM #Result1)
DROP TABLE #Result1
INSERT INTO #SecViols SELECT *FROM #SecViol
TRUNCATE TABLE #SecViol
--/////////////DONE FILTERING//////////////////////////

--the grouped bill items
declare @MatData table
(
    MatGUID uniqueidentifier,
    StoreGUID uniqueidentifier,
    TypeGUID uniqueidentifier,
    GroupGuid uniqueidentifier,
    Qty int
)
insert into @MatData
select fatoraitem.MatGUID, fatoraitem.StoreGUID, fatora.TypeGUID, mada.GroupGUID, ISNULL(SUM(fatoraitem.Qty),0) as Qty
from bi000 fatoraitem
left join bu000 as fatora on fatora.GUID = fatoraitem.ParentGUID
left join mt000 as mada on mada.GUID = fatoraitem.MatGUID
group by fatoraitem.MatGUID, fatoraitem.StoreGUID, fatora.TypeGUID, mada.GroupGUID

INSERT INTO @Materials([Type], MatGUID, GroupGuid, Name,Path) VALUES(2, 0X0, 0X0, 'المجموع الكلي', (SELECT MAX(PATH) FROM @Materials))--FOR THE TOTAL
SELECT [Type], [Level], MatGUID, GroupGuid, Name INTO #ResultS FROM @Materials ORDER BY Path

DECLARE SelectedBillTypes CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT TypeGUID, TypeName FROM @BillTYpesGuids

DECLARE STORESITERATOR CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT StoreGuid, Name FROM @STORES

DECLARE MatIterator CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT MatGuid, Name, Level, Type FROM @Materials

OPEN SelectedBillTypes--BILLS-TYPES
    DECLARE @TypeGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @TypeName varchar(250)
    FETCH NEXT FROM SelectedBillTypes into @TypeGuid, @TypeName
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            OPEN STORESITERATOR--STORES
                DECLARE @StoreGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                DECLARE @StoreName varchar(250)
                FETCH NEXT FROM STORESITERATOR into @StoreGuid, @StoreName
                WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @ColumnQName VARCHAR(MAX)
                    DECLARE @ColumnPName VARCHAR(MAX)
                    DECLARE @AlterStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
                    set @ColumnQName = '[' + @TypeName + '.' + @StoreName + '.Q]'
                    SET @AlterStatement = 'ALTER TABLE #Results ADD ' + @ColumnQName + ' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)'
                    Execute(@AlterStatement)
                    IF(@ParamDisplayType = 1)--EXPANED DISPLAY
                    BEGIN
                        set @ColumnPName = '[' + @TypeName + '.' + @StoreName + '.P]'
                        SET @AlterStatement = 'ALTER TABLE #Results ADD ' + @ColumnPName + ' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)'
                        Execute(@AlterStatement)
                    END
                    OPEN MatIterator--MATS AND GROUPS
                    DECLARE @MatGuid uniqueidentifier, @MatName varchar(250), @MatLevel int, @MatType int
                    FETCH NEXT FROM MatIterator INTO @MatGuid, @MatName, @MatLevel, @MatType
                    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @Price INT, @Quantity INT
                        DECLARE @InsertStatement varchar(MAX)

                        select @Price = CASE WHEN @ParamPriceType = 0X4 THEN Whole
                                             WHEN @ParamPriceType = 0x8 THEN Half
                                             WHEN @ParamPriceType = 0x10 THEN Export
                                             WHEN @ParamPriceType = 0x20 THEN Vendor
                                             WHEN @ParamPriceType = 0x40 THEN Retail
                                             WHEN @ParamPriceType = 0x80 THEN EndUser
                                        END
                                        from mt000 where GUID = @MatGuid
                        IF @MatType = 1
                            SELECT @Quantity = ISNULL(SUM(Qty), 0) FROM @MatData AS T1 WHERE (T1.MatGUID = @MatGUID AND T1.StoreGUID = @StoreGuid And T1.TypeGUID = @TypeGuid)
                        ELSE
                            SET @Quantity = 0
                        set @Price = @Price * @Quantity
                        SET @InsertStatement = 'UPDATE #Results SET ' + @ColumnQName + ' = ' + CAST(@Quantity as VARCHAR(50)) 
                        IF(@ParamDisplayType = 1)--EXPANED DISPLAY
                        BEGIN
                            SET @InsertStatement += ', ' + @ColumnPName + ' = ' + CAST(@Price AS VARCHAR(50))
                        END
                        SET @InsertStatement +=   ' WHERE MatGUID = ''' + CAST(@MatGuid AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''''
                        EXECUTE(@InsertStatement)
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MatIterator INTO @MatGuid, @MatName, @MatLevel, @MatType
                    END
                    CLOSE MatIterator
                    DECLARE @UpdateStatemENT VARCHAR(MAX)
                    DECLARE @Total VARCHAR(MAX)
                    DECLARE @MaxLevel INT
                    SELECT @MaxLevel = ISNULL(MAX(Level),0) FROM #ResultS
                    SET @Total = 'UPDATE #ResultS SET ' + @ColumnQName + ' = ' +
                                '(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(' + @ColumnQName + '), 0) FROM #ResultS AS T2 WHERE T2.Type = 1)'
                    IF(@ParamDisplayType = 1)--EXPANED DISPLAY
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Total += ', ' + @ColumnPName + ' = ' + '(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(' + @ColumnPName + '), 0) FROM #ResultS AS T2 WHERE T2.Type = 1) '
                    END
                    SET @Total +=' WHERE [TYPE] = 2'
                    EXECUTE(@Total)

                    WHILE (@MaxLevel>-1)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @UpdateStatemENT = 'UPDATE #ResultS SET ' + @ColumnQName + ' = ' +
                                               '(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(' + @ColumnQName + '), 0) FROM #ResultS AS T2 WHERE T2.GroupGuid = #ResultS.MatGUID)'
                        IF(@ParamDisplayType = 1)--EXPANED DISPLAY
                        BEGIN
                            SET @UpdateStatemENT += ', ' + @ColumnPName + ' = ' + '(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(' + @ColumnPName + '), 0) FROM #ResultS AS T2 WHERE T2.GroupGuid = #ResultS.MatGUID) '
                        END
                        SET @UpdateStatemENT += ' WHERE [TYPE] = 0 AND Level = ' + CAST(@MaxLevel AS VARCHAR(50))
                        EXECUTE(@UpdateStatemENT)
                        set @MaxLevel -= 1
                    END
                    FETCH NEXT FROM STORESITERATOR into @StoreGuid, @StoreName
                END
            CLOSE STORESITERATOR
            FETCH NEXT FROM SelectedBillTypes into @TypeGuid, @TypeName
        END
CLOSE SelectedBillTypes
SELECT * FROM #ResultS
```

this is the result
[image]

the table header is built in the c++, i get the names from the columns names column name = billtypename.storename.q for quantity or billtypename.storename.p for price. in the c++ i iterate over the columns names in the table and split them and process the header
in the table body i put them as they come from the server